# Storing object on iOS - best solution?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsuserdefaults

I'm building an app for a blog where a user can save their favorite posts.

When they do, I want to store my object which contains: the post's URL, title and image URL.

Should I go for `UserDefaults` (formerly `NSUserDefaults`) or start with `Core Data` right away?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I go for User Defaults or start with Core Data right away?

There are more possibilities here: you can also use plain files or plists, or use sqlite without Core Data. The answer depends on the number of items that you plan to store:

- If you plan to store 1 to 20 items, user defaults would work fine
- If you plan to store 20 to 200 items, plain files or plists would work
- If you plan to store 200+ items, go for Core Data or sqlite, depending on your level of comfort with one of these technologies.

Comment: +1: the numbers may differ for you (Especially for defaults/plists the size of the data matters, but the general advice is sound

Comment: also possible is writing a binary file using NSArchiver ... id say for 20 to 200

Comment: +1: sounds like solid advice to me. Personally, I'd probably go with the Core Data approach here, with the assumption that users could favorite a lot of these items... Plus, with MagicalRecord (see https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord), Core Data is pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks, I think your second solution works best for me as a user's favorites shouldn't be too big.

Answer (score 1):

Since favorites for articles generally wont be 100K item then I would use `NSDictionary` for an item and store them into a `NSMutableArray` and then save them to a file. It is simple to use and you can also export the favorites to a file or even `iCloud` to share between devices.

```
NSMutableDictionary *item = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[item setObject:@"www.google.com" forKey:@"url"];
[item setObject:@"Google" forKey:@"title"];

//Add each item to the Favourites array
//You should declare this outside of the "addToFavourites" function.
NSMutableArray *Favourites = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects: nil];
[Favourites addObject:item];

//Save the Favourites NSMutableArray to the file.
if([Favourites writeToFile:path atomically:NO]) 
   NSLog(@"Favourites are saved!");
```

Comment: Thanks for the example code. I'm now indeed planning on using this trick to store my user's favorites.